# code or plugin ( which one have a higher priority) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web, plugins

my question is about a general scenario. i have written some code for user role and capabilities in wordpress and also install a plugin for that as well.
when everr i change my code for capabilities to give more rights to the role that doesn't work but at the same time when i change the capabilities from the plugin then it works correctly.

**So I want to know**
Is there any priority mechanism in WP which defines the priority for the plugin and the code that which one will be applied first.

here is the **code**...and i am using **role editor plugin**

```
function new_role()
{
    add_role('simple_role','Simple Role',array(
    'read'               =>true,
    'edit_posts'         =>true,
    'publish_posts'      =>true,
    'delete_posts'       =>true,
    'upload_files'       =>true,
    'create_users'       =>true,
    'edit_others_posts'  =>true,
    'delete_others_posts'=>true,
    'edit_themes'=>true
        ));

    add_role('client','Author Role',array('read'=>true, 'edit_posts'=>true,'edit_others_posts'=>true,'delete_posts'=>true));    

    add_role('just_edit','Just Edit',array('read'=>true, 'edit_published_posts'=>true, 'edit_others_posts'=>true, 'edit_posts'=>true, 'create_users'=>true, 'list_users'=>true));
        }
add_action('init','new_role');
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `the code` ... WHERE ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your edit the 2 actions you are adding is from plugins. There is no set order in which wordpress loads plugins (themes are loaded later than plugins btw).

This is where actions come in.

```
add_action('init','new_role');
```

There are 2 more arguments for `add_action` , `$priority` and `$args`.

Priority is default 10 so all hooks added without a priority will be called in order added, so if your plugin is loaded 1st, it will be overwritten by an action that is added later.

The way to get around this is to add a later priority

```
 add_action('init','new_role', 100);
```

It might take some playing around with to ensure your `new_role` function is the one running last.